# Implementing redux form with dual list box

Tags: react-redux, redux-form

I'm setting up redux form in react application, in the form i have dual list box, i cannot shift values from one box to another, vise versa.

other thing im doing checkbox switches it doesn't post value when pages loads when ever i touch/click on it then it does, in both cased true/false but not default false.

for Dual list box

```
    <Field
        name="list"
        type="select"
        onChange={this.handleOnMove}
        component={this.renderReactSelectWrapper}
      />
  renderReactSelectWrapper = props => (
    <DualListBox
      value={props.input.value}
      onChange={props.input.onChange}
      onBlur={props.input.onBlur(props.input.value)}
      options={available}
      selected={selected}
      placeholder="Select"
      simpleValue
      icons={{
        moveLeft: <span key={0}>&lt;</span>,
        moveAllLeft: [<span key={1}>&lt;&lt;</span>],
        moveRight: <span key={2}>&gt;</span>,
        moveAllRight: [<span key={4}>&gt;&gt;</span>],
        moveDown: <span key={5}>&darr;</span>,
        moveUp: <span key={6}>&uarr;</span>
      }}
    />

  );
```

For Checkbox/Switch

```
<Field
                  name="available"
                  id="available"
                  component={this.renderToggleInput}
                />
  renderToggleInput = field => (    <Switch checked={field.input.value} onChange={field.input.onChange} /> );
```

I need to have value shift from one box to another, in the case of checkbox/switch i need to post when page loads.

Answer (score 0):

I was tackling the same problem. I think the issue is you aren't updating the selected array correctly. The follow code worked for me on the selected option.

```
    <DualListBox
      options={options}
      value={this.props.input.value}
      onChange={this.props.input.onChange}
      selected={[...this.props.input.value]}
    />
```